# Регулярное выражения поиск в строке 4-го int

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть вот такой кусок кода, который читает из файла строки и парсит в регулярном выражении в `int`.  Проблема в том, что регулярное выражение пропускает пять `int`, а надо строго четыре.

```java
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

//Reading key in the string
line2 = line2;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\S?\\d*\\d+\\S?\\d");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line2);
while (matcher.find() ) {
    String s = matcher.group(0);
    if (s.replaceAll("\\D", " ").length() == s.length()) {

        integers.add(Integer.parseInt(s));

};
```

Comment: после 4х чисел то что идет, конец строки? или текст, или что?

Comment: После получения пишем в лог файл и удаляю файл который был прочитан.

Comment: Николай, в будущем указывайте язык программирования в метках и диалект РВ в вопросе.  Так людям будет легче вам помочь.

Comment: я вас не про действия в алгоритме спрашивал, а про формат входной строки. приведите конкретные примеры строк ваших

Comment: String line0 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("D:\\temp\\GSM.txt")).get(0);

Comment: ищите просто `\d+` и смотрите кол-во захваченных групп

Comment: Смысла в `if (s.replaceAll("\\D", " ").length() == s.length()) {` нет совсем: вы проверяете длину `1A2` и `1 2`, она всегда будет одинакова. А регулярка для чисел, в которых ровно 4 цифры - `Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d)\\d{4}(?!\\d)")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как вы не указали диалект регулярных выражений, вот вам *POSIX
ERE*, достающее четвертое число:

```
^[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]]+[^[:digit:]]+){3}([[:digit:]]+).*$
```

Пропуск нечисел, три последовательночти число-нечисло (группа 1), число
(группа 2), и пропуск всего остального до конца строки.  Ваше четвёртое
число в группе 2.

---

Из комментариев стало понятно, что вам нужна четвёртая *цифра*.
Это делается так:

```
[^[:digit:]]*[[:digit:]]{3}([[:digit:]])
```

Ваша четвёртая цифра в группе 1.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь но не работает.

Comment: Николай, будьте яснее.  Что значит «не работает»?  У меня всё работает.  Добавьте в вопрос вашу попытку.

Comment: Есть строка (Test 4565)  после работы (РГ) получаю 4565 ваш пример у меня не работает не чего не достает из строки.

Comment: извините не зная как скрин добавить комментарии.

Comment: @НиколайГнап  Ох, ну вы даёте.  Вам _цифра,_ а не число четвёртое нужно.  См. правку.